# How to over StaleElementReferenceException when working with PageFactory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We define our page objects with `@FindBy` annotation like:

```
@FindBy(name="foo")
WebElement fooElement;
```

Whenever I invoke this object `fooElement`, which needs to try identify with above `name=foo`, right?

Then why I will get `StaleElementReferenceException`?

How to overcome this?

I don't want to follow another approach again here (other than page factory) whenever I see `StaleElement` like:

```
WebElement fooElement=driver.findElement(By.name("foo"))
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Please describe your enviorement, language you're using or framework.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me..

```
   public static void StaleHandle(WebElement element) 
   {
       for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
       try
       {
           // whatever actions performed by the element.
           break;
       }
       catch(StaleElementReferenceException e)
       {

            System.out.println("Trying to recover from a stale element :" + e.getMessage());

       }

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

The exception `StaleElementReferenceException` means that the located element is no longer present in the page. It usually appends when the targeted element is located just before the page changes and when it is used just after.
Here is an example to demonstrate the issue :

```java
// trigger the update of the page
driver.findElement(By.name("foo1")).click();

// at this step the page is not yet updated, so the located element is not from the updated page.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("foo2"));

// at this step, the page is updated, the element is now deleted
element.click(); // throws `StaleElementReferenceException`
```

To overcome this issue you can wait for a previous element to become stale :

```java
fooElement1.click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(fooElement1));

fooElement2.click();
```

You can also wait for a new element to become visible:

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(fooElement3));

fooElement2.click();
```

The bottom line is that you need to wait for a specific state which is probably the result of an asynchronous update.

Note that an easy way would be to retry, which would locate the element again and give a new reference. But I wouldn't recommend it since the command could be executed before the update:

```java
try {
    fooElement.click();
} catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
    fooElement.click();
}
```

Comment: "The exception StaleElementReferenceException means that the located element is no longer present in the page" ... that is not quite accurate. The exception will be thrown if the underlying DOM node has been altered in any way (or a parent thereof). The element may still be there but needs to be re-found. The final option of re-finding the element after catching the exception is probably the best method of handling this.

Comment: @Aaron Davis, thanks for the input, but I disagree. This exception is only raised when the located element is no longer present in the page (document or DOM). The drivers (at least Firefox and Chrome) check that the element is a descendant of the main container which is the `document` Object in the window or frame. The exception won't be raised as long as the element is attached to the document, even if you alter an ancestor, a descendant or move the element.

Comment: hmmm, just checked the documentation again. According to it that exception happens when the element is deleted or removed from the DOM (e.g. the element is located then a JS library deletes the underlying DOM node and replaces it with another that has the same information). http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Comment: @Aaron Davis, thanks for pointing to the documentation, but where does it differ from my statement? If an element is deleted from the DOM and replaces with another one, then the former one is no longer present in the page.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of semantics. Yes, technically the DOM instance that the original web element pointed to is gone so it isn't present. In my experience though, when you tell someone the element with the id of "foo" isn't present on the page any longer they open the dev tools and point to it saying "Yes it is!" :-) ... The point I was trying to make was that an element that matches the given selector is still present on the page, just not the one originally found. But rereading my original comment you are correct that I was incorrect :-)

Comment: I know that StaleElement means, whatever was identified earlier will not be active(become stale), due to page/form refresh, or it might recreated with same properties. But how we handle in PageFactory? As i said in my example, we declare these objects in the class, whenever we use it(element.click() etc...), selenium tries to get its identification from the declaration. Then even after the page/frame refresh, when i perform operation which should go back and bring identification, right? Then why i am getting StaleElement? How to overcome this with PageFactory only.

Comment: @Aaron Davis, I get your point. Thought it's dangerous to acknowledge an instance of an element by its attributes or properties. If I were to follow your thinking, then changing the id on an element would result in a new element. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to explain your point of view.

Comment: @Uday, each action on a page object element sends a `FindElement` command, unless you've added the `@CacheLookup` decorator. For instance, executing `fooElement.click()` two times will locate the targeted element 2 times. So to overcome a stale issue, you need to wait for an expected state of the page by waiting for a new element or by waiting for an element to become stale.

Comment: Your last try catch is tricky and may solve the problem. Just let me give a try.